# How to evaluate $\lim f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$; $f_n=nx(1-x)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to evaluate $\lim f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$; $f_n=nx(1-x)^n$?

By using L'Hospital, I've found that $lim f_n= lim \frac{n}{\frac{n(1-x)^{n-1}}{(1-x)^{2n}}}=lim\frac{n(1-x)^{2n}}{n(1-x)^{n-1}}=(1-x)^3$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$ then $f_n(x)=0\to_{n} 0$.

If $x=1$ then $f_n(x)=0\to_{n} 0$.

If $x\in (0,1)$ then $f_n(x)\to_{n} 0$ because:

for a $0<θ<1$ we have that $n^kθ^n\to 0$ for every $k\in \Bbb Z$ because

if 
$k\leq 0$ then it's obvious.

if $k>0$ then there is $b>0:\frac {1}{\theta}=1+b\Rightarrow (\frac {1}{\theta})^n=(1+b)^n$. For every $n>2k$ by using the binomial series we can easily prove that $n^k {\theta}^n\leq (k+1)!(\frac {2}{b})^{k+1}\frac {1}{n}\to 0$.

Thus $nx(1-x)^n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

- Set $f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n}(x)$. Note that for $x=0$ you have$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(0)=0$. Pick an $x \in (0,1)$. Then you have $(1-x)^{n} \to 0$ as $n \to\infty$ and so $\displaystyle 0=f(x) =\lim_{n \to\infty} f_{n}(x)$ for all $x \in(0,1)$. And note that $f(1) =\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(1) =0$. So your limit function $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Hello, Chandrasekhar! When $n \rightarrow \infty$, $nx \rightarrow \infty$ and $(1-x)^n \rightarrow 0$. Then $f(x) = \infty.0$. It is different from $f(x)=0$ isn't?

Comment: @Walterr Note that $(1-x)^{n} \to 0$ faster than $nx$ and hence that will pull $nx$ to $0$. For example look at $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot x^{-2}$ whats the value $0$ right. Thats because $x^{-2} \to 0$ faster than $x$